# Difference between omp ordered and omp critical

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, critical-section

I am trying to understand the difference between omp ordered and omp critical. Do they both not have same semantics? The code written within each of them get to be executed serially and while one thread is in ordered/critical block, other threads wait. I can't see any difference among the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`omp critical` is for **mutual exclusion**, `omp ordered` refers to a specific loop and ensures that the region executes **sequentually in the order of loop iterations**. Therefore `omp ordered` is stronger than `omp critical`, but also only makes sense within a loop.

`omp ordered` has some other clauses, such as `simd` to enforce the use of a single SIMD lane only. You can also specify dependencies manually with the `depend` clause.

Note: Both `omp critical` and `omp ordered` regions have an implicit memory flush at the entry and the exit.